# ofMucConversationLog only persists body of groupchat stanzas

Tags: xmpp, openfire

The **`ofMucConversationLog`** table is the persistence of **`MUC`** room messages that **`openfire`** uses to load MUC history from. This database table only stores the **`body`** portion of the groupchat stanza. I have extensions included in the groupchat message, these portions are lost when the Openfire server is restarted. Is there any solution.

Answer (score 2):

That is a knowing issue by Openfire.

See here: https://igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/OF-817